# Security concerns with user defined postgres jsonb queries in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, security, sql-injection, jsonb

We have a postgres **jsonb** field in Django that allows users to store arbitrary user data. We wish to allow users to query this field but are unsure about the **security implications**.

The model

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("user", null=False)
    meta = JSONField()
```

Query

```
def custom_query(operation, value):
    qs = Item.objects.filter(user=user)

    params = {
        "meta__" + operation: value
    }

    qs = qs.filter(**params)
```

Usage:

Assuming `meta` is `{"a": 1}`.

```
custom_query(operation="contains", value={"a": 1})
custom_query(operation="a", value=1)
```

The above should be valid and equivalent queries.

**Is this a secure way to perform the query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding an allowlist for valid `operation`s and maybe checking the `value` is suitably simple (only strings, for example), but in the presence of other filters that ensure the rows that can be selected are those the user can see, I don't see a problem with this.